# Read js-file http headers from within the js?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, oauth, jwt

The script is attached to a page:

```
<script src='/app/app.js?token={token}'></script>
```

It is served from server with some headers ('Authorization: Bearer ....' to be exact)

Can I access this header from the js in this file?

Comment: Duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: Aren't you looking for the headers returned by the server when calling `GET` on `/app/app.js?token={token}` ?

Comment: For them, but I need to read them in the script /app/app.js, without doing another xhr-request. This is completely different task, then at that question.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is in the first line of the answer in that link: "Unfortunately, there isn't an API to give you the HTTP response headers for your initial page request."

Comment: Well, this is not about page request, but alike. I thought that this is impossible, but just hoped, maybe there is something I missed =))